# data type and calculate average in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, types

I am working on a java code that calculates the average of grades in an array for N of students and it is working fine when I enter grades like {3,4,3} but when I use numbers with decimals like {3.7,2.5,3.2} it starts giving me errors and I want to make a class of data type Students for example.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ArrayAverageProblem { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      System.out.println("Enetr number of students : "); 
      Scanner adnan = new Scanner(System.in); 
      int length = adnan.nextInt(); 
      int[] input = new int[length]; 
      System.out.println("Enter cgpa of students : "); 
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
         input[i] = adnan.nextInt(); 
      } 
      double averageCgpa = averageCgpa(input); 
      System.out.println("Average of students cgpa :  " + averageCgpa); 
      adnan.close(); 
   }   
   public static double averageCgpa(int[] input) { 
      double sum = 0f; 
      for (int number : input) { 
         sum = sum + number; 
      } 
      return sum / input.length; 
   } 
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i improved your code to use double numbers.
note that your grades must be **double** and use **nextDouble()** method to get grade from scanner.
this code is below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enetr number of students : ");

    Scanner adnan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int length = adnan.nextInt();

    double[] input = new double[length];

    System.out.println("Enter cgpa of students : ");

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        input[i] = adnan.nextDouble();

    }

    double averageCgpa = averageCgpa(input);

    System.out.println("Average of students cgpa :  " + averageCgpa);

    adnan.close();

}



public static double averageCgpa(double[] input) {

    double sum = 0f;

    for (double number : input) {

        sum = sum + number;

    }

    return sum / input.length;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the input array datatype. If input array is also expecting double value (with decimal) you need to take the input array as double.

Please change the below line

```
int[] input = new int[length];
```

with

```
double[] input = new double[length];
```

and below line

```
input[i] = adnan.nextInt();
```

with

```
input[i] = adnan.nextDouble();
```

It will work for both the types of numbers(with and without decimal).

I hope this will solve the issue you're facing.

Comment: It is showing errors until now.

Answer (score 0):

In java if both are int, result is also int.
So you can use  sum / Double.valueOf(input.length);